# Is a relatively weakly compact subset of $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ metrizable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a domain with smooth boundary. Let $S\subset W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ be a relatively weakly compact set.

> Is it true that $(S,w)$ is metrizable?

Since $S$ is relatively weakly compact, it is norm-bounded. If I recall correctly, a norm-bounded subset of a Banach space $X$ is metrizable (with respect to the weak topology) if $X^*$ is separable. However, $W^{1,1}(\Omega)^*$ is not separable so the result do not apply here.

I apologize in advance if the question is too simple here.